# intellij idea: generate MANIFEST.MF in gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have gradle project (spring boot app) imported in Intellij Idea. When building with gradle I generate MANIFEST.MF with

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': "${version}"
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': "${project.name}"
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': "1.0"
    }
}
```

however when running and building with Intellij manifest file is not generated (out/production/classes/META-INF) and in application `getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` is null

How can I generat manifest with Intellij?

Comment: AFAIS Gradle does not generate `MANIFEST.MF` either when you run the application with `bootRun`. For creating the application archive in IDE you configure the [Artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html) (jar/war/ear). For the artifact created by IDE automatically generating the `MANIFEST` file  based on gradle configuration for different plugins  is not supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126038 Enable  Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle** to fix this.